# TYPO3 v11 installation

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

We tried to install TYPO3 v11, but the installation stops in step 2, before you can create or select a DB.

The `LocalConfiguration.php` has been created by the installer, but is incomplete (since I cannot create a DB). The result is an incomplete and unusable installation.

System:

```
Windows 10
Apache/2.4.47 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/7.4.19
DB-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.19
PHP-Version: 7.4.19
Composer version 2.0.13
Xampp Control Panel version 3.3.0
```

TYPO3 v9 and TYPO3 v10 are still usable and (re-)still installs fine.
On a VM the installation of TYPO3 v11 fails as well, without any other installed TYPO3 version.

I have no log entries in TYPO3 and also no php_error_log entries.

I have also tried to update TYPO3 v10 to v11, that didn’t work either (had some errors or “site configuration missing” and so on). But the installation process of a fresh version is the preferred way.

Does anyone have the same issue? Maybe some suggestions what we can try to get TYPO3 v11 running?